# Symonfy 3 - FOSUserBundle reset password with REST API

Tags: php, rest, symfony, fosuserbundle, fosrestbundle

I am developing a **`REST`** API with **`Symfony 3`**. Now I want to send an user a link to reset his password. This should be done by sending a request to something like:

```
    "/resetpassword/{userEmail}"
```

How can I create a link for the user to reset the password? I allready now how to send an email by my own, but not how to generate this link or how to handle the link.

Comment: You should generate a unique ID, store this in table user in field like "password_key". When user click on it, display a form to reset his pwd (email, pwd, pwd confirmation). In resetting method, check that unique ID passed is the one you have in your database for this specific user

Answer (score 8):

FOSUserBundle already has all the needed functionality.

1) find the user from requested email
2) check that current user hasn't already requested new password
3) generate confirmation token for user
4) use FOSUserBundle mailer implementation for sending resetting email message
5) update user
6) return response

You could do something like this:

```
    /**
     * @Route("/resetpassword/{userEmail}", name="user_password_reset-request")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function resetPasswordRequestAction(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->query->get('userEmail');
        $user = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->findUserByEmail($email);
        if (null === $user) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }

        if ($user->isPasswordRequestNonExpired($this->container->getParameter('fos_user.resetting.token_ttl'))) {
            throw new BadRequestHttpException('Password request alerady requested');
        }

        if (null === $user->getConfirmationToken()) {
            /** @var $tokenGenerator \FOS\UserBundle\Util\TokenGeneratorInterface */
            $tokenGenerator = $this->get('fos_user.util.token_generator');
            $user->setConfirmationToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        }

        $this->get('fos_user.mailer')->sendResettingEmailMessage($user);
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \DateTime());
        $this->get('fos_user.user_manager')->updateUser($user);

        return new Response(Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```